# OpenVAS scan only local network ip

Tags: linux, networking, openvas

Using OpenVAS if I try to target localhost or ip router in my local network all is ok, and the task ends up, but if I try to scan a public IP it stop to 1% or 2%.

This is my config:

> **Kali 2.0 64bit for VMWare**
>
> **Network in Bridge**
>
> **OpenVAS 8 pre-installed**

Some details (netstat):

```
root@kali:~# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:9390          *:*                     LISTEN      8560/openvasmd  
tcp        0      0 localhost:9391          *:*                     LISTEN      8561/openvassd: Wai
tcp        0      0 localhost:9392          *:*                     LISTEN      8559/gsad
```

And "check setup":

```
root@kali:~# openvas-check-setup 
openvas-check-setup 2.3.0

Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.0.1.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner CA Certificate is present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner server certificate is valid and present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem.
        OK: NVT collection in /var/lib/openvas/plugins contains 45313 NVTs.
        WARNING: Signature checking of NVTs is not enabled in OpenVAS Scanner.
        SUGGEST: Enable signature checking (see http://www.openvas.org/trusted-nvts.html).
        OK: The NVT cache in /var/cache/openvas contains 45313 files for 45313 NVTs.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=2.8.17.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /var/lib/redis/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /var/lib/redis/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 6.0.1.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager client certificate is valid and present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: At least one user exists.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 146.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 146.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database contains information about 45306 NVTs.
        OK: OpenVAS SCAP database found in /var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db.
        OK: OpenVAS CERT database found in /var/lib/openvas/cert-data/cert.db.
        OK: xsltproc found.
Step 3: Checking user configuration ... 
        WARNING: Your password policy is empty.
        SUGGEST: Edit the /etc/openvas/pwpolicy.conf file to set a password policy.
Step 4: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ... 
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is present in version 6.0.1.
Step 5: Checking OpenVAS CLI ... 
        OK: OpenVAS CLI version 1.4.0.
Step 6: Checking Greenbone Security Desktop (GSD) ... 
        SKIP: Skipping check for Greenbone Security Desktop.
Step 7: Checking if OpenVAS services are up and running ... 
        OK: netstat found, extended checks of the OpenVAS services enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is running and listening only on the local interface.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is listening on port 9391, which is the default port.
        WARNING: OpenVAS Manager is running and listening only on the local interface.
        This means that you will not be able to access the OpenVAS Manager from the
        outside using GSD or OpenVAS CLI.
        SUGGEST: Ensure that OpenVAS Manager listens on all interfaces unless you want
        a local service only.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is listening on port 9390, which is the default port.
        WARNING: Greenbone Security Assistant is running and listening only on the local interface.
        This means that you will not be able to access the Greenbone Security Assistant from the
        outside using a web browser.
        SUGGEST: Ensure that Greenbone Security Assistant listens on all interfaces.
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is listening on port 9392, which is the default port.
Step 8: Checking nmap installation ...
        WARNING: Your version of nmap is not fully supported: 6.49BETA4
        SUGGEST: You should install nmap 5.51 if you plan to use the nmap NSE NVTs.
Step 10: Checking presence of optional tools ...
        OK: pdflatex found.
        OK: PDF generation successful. The PDF report format is likely to work.
        OK: ssh-keygen found, LSC credential generation for GNU/Linux targets is likely to work.
        WARNING: Could not find rpm binary, LSC credential package generation for RPM and DEB based targets will not work.
        SUGGEST: Install rpm.
        WARNING: Could not find makensis binary, LSC credential package generation for Microsoft Windows targets will not work.
        SUGGEST: Install nsis.

It seems like your OpenVAS-8 installation is OK.
```

This probably could help me, but looking on Google and here on StackOverflow did not find anything: **WARNING: OpenVAS Manager is running and listening only on the local interface.**

What can I check and what can I do for scan a public ip ?

*Given my limited skills on Linux, I ask you to be very specific. **Thanks***

Comment: As this question does NOT involve programming, it belongs on **[superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)** or **[serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)**. You are more likely to quickly get valid answers there.

Comment: You're probably right. I found other questions regarding OpenVAS here... But is possibile to move it? it would be perfect.

Comment: Can you, at least, ping to any public IP?